# Change the image display on listview depends on the gender Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

Im creating an app that displays the students from sqlite. The image of male and female is in the drawable and i want to display it depends on the gender of the students. I dont know the code to be applied. This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<Student> GetAll;
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ListView lv;
    Context context = this;
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        //Add below lines to your original code
        try {
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            dbhelper.openDataBase();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        //Till here

        GetAll = dbhelper.getAll(index);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
    }

    public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ViewAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return GetAll.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            }

            final TextView names = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView gender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);

            names.setText(GetAll.get(position).getname());
            gender.setText(GetAll.get(position).getgender());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

> XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/male"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"

            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="7dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have almost on it. While populating the list, you got the textViews for name and gender. You just need to get the ImageView and set the corresponding image from your drawable folder.

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        }

        final TextView names = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView gender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);

        names.setText(GetAll.get(position).getname());
        gender.setText(GetAll.get(position).getgender());

        // Get ImageView 
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // Check if it is male or female and set the image
        if(GetAll.get(position).getgender().equals("MALE")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.male_image);
        }else{
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_image);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ImageView.setImageResource` for setting image for ImageView according to Gender:

```
final ImageView imgGender = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imgGender.setImageResource((GetAll.get(position).getgender().equals("male") ? 
                                R.drawable.male:R.drawable.female));
```

Comment: why is it theres a "?"

Comment: dude "?" is part of ternary operator which i have used instead of using if-else ladder

Comment: @GemUbaldo: also you can also use `equalsIgnoreCase` for making incentive comparison

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I think you meant imgGender.setImageResource() ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    final TextView gender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageVIew)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    gender.setText(GetAll.get(position).getgender());

    if(GetAll.get(position).getgender().equals("male"))
     {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
     }
   else
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
```

Comment: Use `equals` instead of `==` for comparing Strings

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes you are right . use `equals` or `equalignorecase` .

Answer (score 0):

First, declare your ImageView:

```
ImageView genderImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Assuming that getGender returns a string value (eg. 'male' or 'female') and your gender images are named 'female_icon' and 'male_icon':

```
genderImage.setImageResource(GetAll.get(position).getgender().equals("female") ? R.drawable.female_icon : R.drawable.male_icon);
```

A better way to do this would be to provide a 3rd icon in case the value for gender is somehow neither 'female' nor 'male'...

```
String genderString = GetAll.get(position).getgender();

if (genderString.equals("female")) {
    genderImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_icon);
} else if (genderString.equals("male")) {
    genderImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.male_icon);
} else {
    genderImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown_gender_icon);
}
```